# How to skip the PR workflow on GitHub Actions when the base branch is up to date

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, pull-request

Is it possible to either trigger a GitHub Actions `on: pull_request` workflow only if the base ref is out of date, or else to have the PR workflow stop quickly (with a success state) when the base ref is up to date?

This almost works:

```
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  test:
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' || github.event.pull_request.merge_commit_sha != 'null' }}
```

Sometimes when the PR's base is up to date, the `merge_commit_sha` is indeed `null`, but this `if:` condition is not reliable: when I pushed a second commit on my PR, the `merge_commit_sha` was no longer `null`, even though `main` had had no new commits.

##### Why I care

In our workflow for development of projects hosted on GitHub, we use CI to run our test suites on `push` and on `pull_request` and require that CI pass before merging (pretty standard stuff).

Now, we would like to optimize our workflows.

- If a PR is based on an older commit in the ancestry of `origin/main`, then the `pull_request` run is important because it runs CI on the result of doing the merge.
- But if a PR is based on the tip of `origin/main`, the `push` and `pull_request` runs are exercising exactly the same code and so the PR CI run is redundant.
- We always want `on: push` because that's relevant on branches that aren't PR'd yet too.

##### Other things I tried

Scouring through the full `github.event` context, I still can't find a variable that exactly matches my desired condition.

I've also tried `on: pull_request: types: [synchronize]` but that's not the trigger I'm looking for.

I have found questions here and documentation online about making a PR's CI run fail if the base branch is not up to date, but not how to skip the redundant CI run when the PR is up to date.